# Django: format DateField inherited by the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with a `DateField`:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, primary_key=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

and i generate a form from it:

```
class SecondStepForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Info
            exclude = ('userprofile',)
```

The problem is that i want to format the date input. I know it is possible with `forms.DateField`:

```
   birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y'), input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y',))
```

but how to tell django that it should make a form from the model except for the date field where it should use `forms.DateField`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're there already. Just put that `birth_date` definition at the top level of the form, before the Meta class, and it will override the default field.